# iPhone: Battery functions?

Tags: iphone

Are there Battery related API:s available in iPhone SDK? I want to find the battery draining state and other things related to battery from my application.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/BatteryStatus/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008812) the example project from Apple's Dev Center showing how you can read battery status.

Answer (score 2):

UIDevice has the following properties:

**batteryLevel**

The battery charge level for the device.

@property (nonatomic,readonly) float batteryLevel

Discussion

Battery level ranges from 0.0 (fully discharged) to 1.0 (100% charged). Before accessing this property, ensure that battery monitoring is enabled.

If battery monitoring is not enabled, battery state is UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown and the value of this property is –1.0.

**batteryMonitoringEnabled**

A Boolean value indicating whether battery monitoring is enabled (YES) or not (NO).

@property (nonatomic,getter=isBatteryMonitoringEnabled) BOOL batteryMonitoringEnabled

Discussion

Enable battery monitoring only when your application needs to be notified of changes to the battery state. Otherwise, disable battery monitoring. The default value is NO.

**batteryState**

The battery state for the device.

@property (nonatomic,readonly) UIDeviceBatteryState batteryState

Discussion

The value for batteryState is one of the constants in “UIDeviceBatteryState.”

If battery monitoring is not enabled, the value of this property is UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown.